# HttpContext.Current.Items.TryGetValue inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, .net

.Net 4.5 MVC 5 application.

I want to use to use TryGetValue on HttpContext.Current.Items but I'm getting the error DictionaryExtensions.TryGetValue ... is inaccessible due to its protection level.

What am I missing?

Comment: could you please post your code here, since it sounds a bit odd. thank you.

Comment: the relevant code is ONE LINE: 
if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.TryGetValue(sKey, out value)) ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HttpContext.Current.Items is System.Collections.IDictionary (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) which is different than System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299639(v=vs.110).aspx)

HttpContext.Current.Items[key] returns null if the key does not exist so it does not need a TryGetValue method.

Answer (score 1):

HttpContext.Current.Items is an IDictionary

TryGetValue is a method on Dictionary().

It seems that in the underlying libraries, someone has created their own extension method on IDictionary for that purpose, but it must be an internal class.

Cast as a Dictionary with the right types, and you should be ok.

Comment: TryGetValue is a method on IDictionary https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299639(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing any reference, its just that TryGetValue is method available only on type Dictionary

Items collections of HttpContext is IDictionary based key-value collections which is shared across a single HTTPRequest. i.e. HttpContext.Current.Items is returning a IDictionary. It does not have any known type for intellisense to know about this method;

you may want use it as below.

```
HttpContext.Current.Items["ModuleInfo"] = "Custom Module Info”

string contextData = (string)(HttpContext.Current.Items["ModuleInfo"]);
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be confusing the 'Items' property of the httpcontext which is a IDictionary, and the values contained therein which are 'Object' and need to be cast.